# Is there a way to specify the order in which ApplicationScoped managed beans are initialized?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, tomcat7, managed-bean

I was wondering because I came across a peculiar behavior with `ApplicationScoped` managed beans and a class with a

```
static {
    //some code that accesses an application bean
}
```

section in it that extends an `ApplicationScoped` bean

I am using JSF 2.1.17 with Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just bad design in first place. Application scoped beans are not static, they are just application scoped.

Inject the one as a `@ManagedProperty` of the other and perform the job in `@PostConstruct` instead.

Comment: I figured this was the case, but I am still curious as to if you can specify order of `ApplicationScoped` bean initialization.

Comment: This should not be a concern at all if you just inject the one as a `@ManagedProperty` of the other. JSF will then guarantee that the one is ready with (post)construction before injection, if not done yet.

Comment: I know it isn't an issue and I plan on restructuring the bad design (it was like this because we were on older libraries jsf1), but I am still curious is there a way to order which one initializes first?

Comment: No, there isn't. If you're actually concerned about the ordering, just use `@ManagedProperty` to enforce that the injected one is guaranteed to be ready before being accessed.